# Create a rippley background in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, background

[image]

how do I create a background in CSS as in the picture.? or should I just take a screenshot and fill the background with the screenshot image?

Comment: Look at it like this: if you can create this in a design tool like Sketch, Figma, etc. using background gradients, then you can recreate it in CSS. Otherwise using a background image would be the easiest alternative.

Comment: Where have you taken the screenshot from? Is it possible to inspect the element to see what the example has already done?

Comment: you could use a combination of different gradients to make it look like this.

Answer (score -2):

It is impossible to do something like that in CSS.

I suggest you take a screenshot and then use some AI, like https://cleanup.pictures/, to remove the text.

If it is a website, then you can take the full image from the inspection panel, as suggested by @Harrison.

Comment: You can use inset background shadows, it's just going to take quite a lot of time and effort to make an inticate ripple gradient background like this.